# How to use Custom Action of Setup Project (vdproj) with .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-setup-proje

I would like to create an installer for my self-hosted service written in .NET Core 3.1. I'm using `Visual Studio 2019` so I had to install `VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects` and this allowed me to create `Setup Project`.

So, everything now works ok, except that I can't run any code during the installation! In standard .NET Framework there was `Installer` class that enabled me to inject some functions, like "register and start service". But .NET Core has nothing like that!

So how can I run extra C# code after the installation is finished?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that `Installer class` is not supported anymore and probably won't be in foreseeable future.

The workaround is to you the service exe itself as as a host for custom code, run be parameters.

Steps:

1. In the Solution, where your .Net Core service lies add the "Setup Project" project. (it must be the same solution)
2. Go to `File System` -> `Application Folder` and add `PublishItemsOutputGroup`
3. Go to custom actions view and add a custom action `PublishItemsOutputGroup` to `Install` with your exe name selected. (e.g. it should say `(name) PublishItemsOutputGroup from MyApiService (Active)`)
4. Set `arguments` to `/my_Install`
5. Go you form `Main` in the service and add something like:

> ```
> if (args.Length == 1)
> {
>        File.AppendAllText("test_install_ca.txt", args[0]);
>        return;
> }
> ```

6. Once you run it, you will find `test_install_ca.txt` in `System32` dir with the content `/my_Install`